# Can setFetchSize and setObject work together for jConnect driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-iq, jconnect

I'm programing against a sybase IQ database, and get weird error when combining setFetchSize together with setObject.

- sybase IQ server version: 16.0
- jdbc driver: jconn4 16.0
- java 8

Let's say we have following code snippet:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM demo.sakila.actor WHERE last_update > ? ORDER BY last_update ASC";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setObject(1, "2007-1-1 00:00:00");
pstmt.setFetchSize(100);
pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Which ends up with error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SA: Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 0.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:762)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsParam.prepareForSend(TdsParam.java:225)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.checkParams(ParamManager.java:1193)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsCursor.tdsCursor(TdsCursor.java:731)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.TdsCursor.open(TdsCursor.java:321)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java:2365)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SybPreparedStatement.java:272)
```

Looks like it's caused by missing parameter. If I remove the line of setting fetchSize, the program works without problem.

Anyone knows is it expected behavior?

Comment: Please show the query, and post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Thanks for reminding, I've updated the question.